# Optional Order By in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-order-by

I have a somewhat complex stored procedure. I want to enable users to select columns to order by. They should be able to select as many or few columns as wanted.

Is there some way to implement this in the stored procedure? How can I pass column names into the procedure and then reflect those int he order by clause? Noting there will be a variable number of columns.

I understand how to pass parameters, just don't know if this will be possible to dynamically build the order by clause within a stored procedure

Comment: Yes, by using dynamic SQL - build up your SQL statements inside your procedure, with or without the `ORDER BY` clause - then execute that SQL statement using `exec sp_executesql ....`

Comment: create dynamic query and execute with sp_executesql

Comment: ... and be sure to protect against SQL Injection.

Comment: Or, you could sort the rows on the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building the `ORDER BY` dynamically is pretty straightforward. I assume you are passing parameters like:

```
@OrderByCol1 NVARCHAR(255),
@OrderByCol2 NVARCHAR(255),
...etc...
```

These may or may not include direction too, e.g. `N'MyColumn DESC'`. So then you can build this together as follows:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT ... 
  FROM ...  
  WHERE ... 
  ORDER BY NULL'
  + COALESCE(',' + @OrderByCol1, '')
  + COALESCE(',' + @OrderByCol2, '')
  ...etc...;

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Since we apparently need to recap the entire SQL injection conversation every time an answer even mentions dynamic SQL, I will add some examples.

If they can only ever sort ascending, then you can prevent SQL injection by simply wrapping the parameter values in `QUOTENAME()`.

```
  + COALESCE(',' + QUOTENAME(@OrderByCol1), '')
  + COALESCE(',' + QUOTENAME(@OrderByCol2), '')
```

Otherwise, you could also split the parameters apart by space (assuming your column names don't contain spaces, which they shouldn't!), and validate that the left side is always present in `sys.columns`.

```
IF @OrderByCol1 IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
     WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable')
     AND name = LTRIM(LEFT(@OrderByCol1, CHARINDEX(' ', @OrderByCol1)))
)
BEGIN
  SET @sql += ',' + @OrderByCol1;
END
```

You may also want to have checks there in case they pass nothing into any of the parameters, or only pass a value into parameter #4, etc. The above does that.

It might be better to pass these in using a TVP, then you don't have to place arbitrary and artificial limits on the number of columns they can choose. Here is one example of a three-column TVP which allows you to pass in a set of order by columns, dictate the order they're applied, and indicate the sort order for each. This also makes it slightly easier to check that each column is really a column (and hey, if you name a column `[1;truncate table dbo.something]`, you deserve what you get...).

First, create the following user-defined table type in your database:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.OrderByColumns AS TABLE
(
  [Sequence] TINYINT PRIMARY KEY,
  ColumnName SYSNAME NOT NULL,
  Direction VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ASC'
);
```

Then:

```
DECLARE @x dbo.OrderByColumns;

INSERT @x SELECT 1, N'name', 'ASC';
INSERT @x SELECT 2, N'ID', 'DESC';
INSERT @x SELECT 3, N'1;truncate table dbo.whatever', 'DESC';

-- the above could be a parameter to your stored procedure
-- and could be populated in a DataTable in your application

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT ... FROM ...
  WHERE ... ORDER BY NULL';

SELECT @sql += ',' + QUOTENAME(x.ColumnName) + ' ' + x.Direction
FROM sys.columns AS c
INNER JOIN @x AS x
ON c.name = x.ColumnName
AND c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable')
ORDER BY x.[Sequence] OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

PRINT @sql;
```

While you can do this using `CASE`, generating the `ORDER BY` dynamically - particularly when it influences the plan choice - can actually be better for performance. With a static query, you get a plan for whatever `@order_column` was first, then it gets reused even if a different ordering column might have led to a different, more efficient plan. Different plans are likely with different `ORDER BY` clauses because these require different SORT operators. You can get around this problem somewhat using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, which ensures you get a new plan generated every time, but now you pay for a compile cost every single time, even if the same order by is always, or almost always, used.

When you use dynamic SQL, each version of the query is optimized separately. Plan cache bloat is a concern that is somewhat offset by the `optimize for ad hoc workloads` server setting. This prevents SQL Server from caching the whole plan for a specific variation of a query until that specific variation has been used twice.

Comment: `set @orderbycol1='1; truncate table dbo.ReallyImportantTable'`

Comment: @Ben yes, did you see I have a whole paragraph about how you could thwart SQL injection?

Comment: my fault. Chalk it up to multi-tasking while writing comments!

Comment: @AaronBertrand nice answer, I have written similar solutions. Later on I added a 'recorder' to see what kind of sorts the users actually requested. I had in total 64 options, but 3 of the options were responsible for 95%+ so after that conclusion I put a switch at the start of the procedure to jump directly to sub_procedure[1..3] for those three 95%+ sorts. The rests of the procedure remained in place. That was my rescue from the point of view of performance.

Comment: @Paul Was this on 2000? Since SQL Server 2005, we've had statement-level recompile, so shuffling certain things off into a different procedure shouldn't have really changed anything wrt the plan cache.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, yes it was on 2000. Using more than one procedure was just for the overview, the 3 procedures had a fixed order by which gave more insight on indexes needed.

Answer (score 5):

You can assemble the SQL dynamically and execute it using `sp_executesql`. However, that loses you some of the performance and security gains that you get from using a parameterized stored procedure that isn't dynamic.

If the possible ORDER BY columns are a finite list, you can use a CASE WHEN in the ORDER BY clause to alter the ordering based on a passed-in parameter.  E.g. if you've passed in a parameter called @order_column, you can do

```
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @order_column='ColumnA'
THEN ColumnA END
CASE WHEN @order_column='ColumnB'
THEN ColumnB END
```

Comment: Well, actually, generating the `ORDER BY` dynamically - particularly when it influences the plan choice - can actually be *better* for performance. With a static query, you get a plan for whatever `@order_column` was first, then it gets reused even if a different ordering column might have led to a different, more efficient plan. When you use dynamic SQL, each version of the query is optimized separately. Plan cache bloat is a concern that is somewhat offset by `optimize for ad hoc workloads`.

Comment: Voted up because you doesn't relied on dynamic sql but Aaron is right unfortunately. If OP is not paging server side I suggest to order by client side.

Comment: @JacobMattison how would you write it with more than one column?